# sbt interactive mode commands do not complete under Babun

Tags: windows, scala, sbt, interactive, babun

I cannot run any command in sbt in interactive mode, while the same commands work if used on the command line.
I am running sbt 0.13.13 with Java 1.8.0_102-b14 on Windows 7 in Babun Cygwin.
I have created a minimal Scala project in order to troubleshoot other sbt problems. sbt can compile my project and can enter interactive mode, but then it gets stuck with any command. Why is that / how can I troubleshoot this?

```
{ sbtXmpl }  > ./sbt projects
+ java -jar ./build/buildcommon/sbt-launch.jar projects
[info] Loading global plugins from C:\Users\MyName\.sbt\0.13\plugins
[info] Loading project definition from C:\dev\sbtXmpl\project
[info] Set current project to root (in build file:/C:/dev/sbtXmpl/)
[info] In file:/C:/dev/sbtXmpl/
[info]     core
[info]   * root
[info]     util
{ sbtXmpl }  > ./sbt
+ java -jar ./build/buildcommon/sbt-launch.jar
[info] Loading global plugins from C:\Users\MyName\.sbt\0.13\plugins
[info] Loading project definition from C:\dev\sbtXmpl\project
[info] Set current project to root (in build file:/C:/dev/sbtXmpl/)
> projects
// This never returns
^C
zsh: command not found: projects
```

Comment: Actually, this probably has more to do with Cygwin / Babun and its interactions with Windows. I cannot run Python interactively either, but I can run "python SomeScript.py"

Comment: Yes. This looks like what you typed (`projects`) was not sent to `sbt`, since `zsh` noticed it after `sbt` was killed. That would probably be an error at a higher-level than `sbt`.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably related to how a console Java app (sbt) interacts with the shell.
I was able to solve the problem for sbt by adding the fragment below in the script I use to run sbt:

```
if [ "$(expr substr $(uname -s) 1 6)" == "CYGWIN" ];then
    #Ensure that sbt uses the correct terminal settings
    CYG_OPTS="-Djline.terminal=jline.UnixTerminal -Dsbt.cygwin=true"
    #Prevent erase, kill, werase, and rprnt special characters 
    stty -icanon min 1 -echo > /dev/null 2>&1
fi

#launch sbt
java $CYG_OPTS $JAVA_OPTS -jar $SBT_LAUNCHER "$@"
```

I have not yet found a solution for Python.

[REPL programs (sbt, python) do not complete under Babun](https://github.com/babun/babun/issues/724)

[Babun breaks on winows apps with console input](https://github.com/babun/babun/issues/491)